# DNS issue in K8s cluster while dealing with multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, coredns

We have a K8s cluster(1 master, 3 nodes) with multiple namespaces created.
All pods are in Running state including coredns in kube-system. We face "host name cannot be resolved" kind of error sometimes(mostly when scale up/down the pods). When we check the coredns logs, got the following error

```
reflector.go:205] github.com/coredns/coredns/plugin/kubernetes/controller.go:318: Failed to list /*v1.Namespace: namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:coredns" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

We were not getting any error when there was only one default namespace.

K8s cluster initialized with the following command:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=10.50.122.204
```

Network: Flannel
kubectl,kubelet,kebeadm version: 1.13.3

Do we need to do anything specific for network or dns side when creating multiple namespaces?
Ideally, pods should be able to resolve the service name.
Thanks in advance.

> **Update:**
>   *Issue got fixed by changing the base image of Docker. I was using the base image which is 
>   having some security restrictions (image from 
>   private registry).*

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: This  issue got fixed, by changing the base image of Docker. I was using base image which is having some security restrictions (image from private registry). @MWZ